# Can I get a failing iMessage to timeout faster?

Tags: macos, messages

I am working out some kinks in an Applescript that is using iMessage.  As part of my development process, I am dealing with messages that are not able to send successfully.  I have to wait for the blue bar to finally go all the way across the screen and these messages to finally give me the red "Not Delivered" message before I can continue with my testing.  This can take a ridiculous amount of time sometimes (as I write this, I have an attachment that has been trying to send for half an hour).  Until sending the message actually times out, I cannot send any other messages to the recipient.

Is there a way to manually make the failing message stop attempting to send before it automatically times by sending a signal / killing a process?

Comment: You can automate stopping all network interfaces. If you do that manually does that free your test harness up to start a new test?

Comment: @bmike, I tried disabling WiFi, and it does not make the message immediately time out.  Do you mean something more dramatic?

Comment: No - shutting off network (assuming you only use Wifi) was the only trick I had up my sleeve. Also, this is likely highly intentional on Apple’s part to limit messaging when push notifications go to an offline device. Might you be throttled by Apple for sending a lot of messages from your IP address?

Comment: @bmike I really doubt it is throttling.  I haven't sent a ton of messages, and I am just trying to send to my own Apple ID right now...

Comment: Glad to hear - that’s odd why your own address would be sending. Why not put the file in iCloud and be done with it?

Comment: @bmike - My own address wouldn't be the eventual destination.  This is just a test to work out the kinks...